# Import images from kitematic to boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am on OS X.

I have been using kitematic for some time now, but today I wanted to switch to boot2docker, as I sometimes find kitematic very abstract to the user.

The problem I am facing is, is there a way to use all the images that I built in kitematic, in boot2docker. It took me considerable time to build 2 of them, and I certainly don't want to build them again.

I think one way would be to first push the image to docker hub using kitematic, and then pull it in boot2docker. But, that would consume a lot of data, as the image is pretty large.

The images are right now stored somewhere on my mac, so there must be some way to directly use them in boot2docker, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `docker save` to [save](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#save) the image to a tar file and `docker load` to [load](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#load) it back in your other vm.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `docker-machine`. Then use `docker-machine env dev | source` to access your docker images via the docker CLI.